# Can't send Email: Error 500 or 403 when trying to use SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail

Tags: javascript, rest

I am getting a Internal Server 500 error when trying to send an email using the `SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail` in my SharePoint Online App. It is worth noting that I am working from a custom `.aspx` page that does not inherit from the Masterpage, and using AngularJS (thus the `$http`).

If I change the urlTemplate to use the hostWeb instead of the AppWeb, I get a `403 forbidden`. Is there a library I need to include since I am using a `custom.aspx` page instead of the `default.aspx` page that comes when creating an App?

```
var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";   

$http({
contentType: 'application/json',
url: urlTemplate,
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify({
    'properties': {
        '__metadata': {
            'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
        },
        'From': 'myname@myname.org',
        'To': {
            'results': ['yourname@myname.org']
        },
                            'Body': 'Hello',
                            'Subject': 'remember'
}
}),
headers: {
"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
},
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
$scope.data = data;
alert("Email Sent!");
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
$scope.status = status;
alert("Email FAil!");
});
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not that I can recall. It has been a while since that project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this post is a bit old but I had the same problem and found out I had to set the SMTP outgoing in my Sharepoint Central Administrator.

- Open the SharePoint 2013 Central Administration and go to System
  Settings and ClickConfigure outgoing e-mail settings. image This link
  is external to TechNet Wiki. It will open in a new window.
- Click the email settings to configure the outgoing email server. set 
  the Outbound SMTP server to your email server. From address should be
  any email address that can acceptably display in the "from" of email 
  and Reply-to address similarly.

([Reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30665.step-by-step-setup-for-outgoing-email-setting-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1.aspx))

Comment: Can you please add details about how to do that, to make it really helpful

Comment: Edited my answer, Hope it helps :)